# Adding rows to a datatable while looping through a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview, datatable

I've got a datagridview populated from a MySQL db. 
I'm looping through it to validate the info and, when info is validated, adding records to a datatable.

The problem i've got is that my current code only adds the first record. 
I expected it to add a record, move on and then add another record and move on etc.

Any ideas?

```
    Private Sub ProcessorWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles ProcessorWorker.DoWork
    Console.WriteLine("ProcessorWorker Invoked...")
    Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Dim entryid As String = " "
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In orderslist.Rows

            If row.Cells("member_id").Value.ToString IsNot Nothing Then
                entryid = row.Cells("entry_id").Value.ToString
                If entryid <> "" Then
                Dim memberid As String = row.Cells("member_id").Value.ToString

                    Dim cn1 As New MySqlConnection
                    cn1.ConnectionString = ###myconnectionstring###
                    Dim vm_components As New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM website_orders WHERE order_id= '" & entryid & "'", cn1)
                    Dim vm_components_table As New DataTable
                    vm_components.Fill(vm_components_table)
                    Dim row1 As DataRow
                    row1 = vm_components_table.Select("order_id = '" & entryid & "'").FirstOrDefault()
                    If Not row1 Is Nothing Then
                        If row1.Item("cart_id") IsNot Nothing Then web_cartid = row1.Item("cart_id").ToString
                        If row1.Item("email") IsNot Nothing Then web_email = row1.Item("email").ToString
                        If row1.Item("member_id") IsNot Nothing Then web_memberid = row1.Item("member_id").ToString
                        If row1.Item("firstname") IsNot Nothing Then web_firstname = row1.Item("firstname").ToString
                        If row1.Item("lastname") IsNot Nothing Then web_lastname = row1.Item("lastname").ToString
                        If row1.Item("company") IsNot Nothing Then web_company = row1.Item("company").ToString
                        If row1.Item("address1") IsNot Nothing Then web_address1 = row1.Item("address1").ToString
                        If row1.Item("address2") IsNot Nothing Then web_address2 = row1.Item("address2").ToString
                        If row1.Item("city") IsNot Nothing Then web_city = row1.Item("city").ToString
                        If row1.Item("postcode") IsNot Nothing Then web_postcode = row1.Item("postcode").ToString
                    End If

                    dt.Columns.Add("Product Ordered", Type.GetType("System.String"))
                    dt.Columns.Add("Operating System", Type.GetType("System.String"))
                    dt.Columns.Add("Company", Type.GetType("System.String"))
                    dt.Columns.Add("Customer", Type.GetType("System.String"))
                    dt.Columns.Add("Email Address", Type.GetType("System.String"))

                    WebOrders.DataSource = dt
                    Dim dr As DataRow
                    dr = dt.NewRow
                    dr("Product Ordered") = web_servertype
                    dr("Operating System") = web_os
                    dr("Company") = "WORLD"
                    dr("Customer") = web_firstname & " " & web_lastname
                    dr("Email Address") = web_email
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                    WebOrders.AllowUserToAddRows = False
                End If
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know why and/or who deleted my comment but the accepted answer should address the following issues: 1) Swallowing exception is a bad practices. 2) BackgroundWorker has it's own "error handling" mechanism. 3) Possibility of cross-thread exceptions. 4) Always dispose IDisposable objects. 5) Always use prepared/parameterized SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you put the add statements inside the for each loop. So in the second iteration you're trying to add an already existing column named `Product Ordered` to the `DataTable`. That's why an exception is thrown and you reach the catch block. The solution is to put the add statements before the for each loop.